# Finding the Geometric Median of N points in 2D Euclidean space when its X co-ordinate is given.

Tags: geometry, numerical-methods, numerical-optimization

I have a given cluster of N points in 2-space. The goal is to find the geometric median of this cluster, and the x co-ordinate of the geometric median is known. What is the most computationally efficient way to find the y coordinate of the geometric median?

I have got a working solution iterating over the distance sum to find the minimum using Newton's method, but this is computationally intensive. It is also unpredictable in terms of convergence time.

To clarify, I am working with Euclidian distances, not Manhattan distances or distances squared.

Comment: Could you write the objective function? Because the Median is the point which minimizes the sum of absolute deviation (What you call Manhattan Distance) while the Mean is what minimizes the Euclidean Distance. You see the contradiction?

Comment: I thought the geometric median was for Euclidean distances while the geometric mean was for Manhattan distances.

Comment: The best option would be to clearly define what you're after. Given a set of $ { 
\left\{ {x}_{i} \right\} }_{i = 1}^{N}, \; {x}_{i} \in \mathbb{R}^{2} $, what is the objective function you want to minimize?